# update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to default

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, software-installation, dpkg

On Ubuntu 17.10 installation hangs when installing ebtables package on the following:

```
Preparing to unpack .../ebtables_2.0.10.4-3.5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...                                                     
Unpacking ebtables (2.0.10.4-3.5ubuntu2) ...               
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...        
Processing triggers for systemd (234-2ubuntu12.1) ...      
Setting up ebtables (2.0.10.4-3.5ubuntu2) ...              
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ebtables.service → /lib/systemd/system/ebtables.service.   
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
```

The output of ps:

```
root      4432  0.0  0.0   4592   840 pts/4    S+   10:37   0:00 /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/ebtables.postinst configure
```

Does it look like the script cannot complete?

How can I troubleshoot further?

Is it an alternate way to install an ebtables?

Answer (score 3):

They overhauled the entire service booting method which means if you use 'old school' service control you get this weird message.

It's actually fairly simple, at least on Raspian; do this:

```
sudo systemctl start|stop <service>
```

There's other commands you can use too, but as you got this error message, presumably you followed an old blog post that said to type something like:

```
sudo update-rc.d <service> stop
```

and you got that error. The fix, for example, would be:

```
sudo systemctl stop isc-dhcp-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2013/05/msg01109.html

Quote:

> None of this should affect anyone since in practice there will be no
>   noticable difference other than the addition of a warning if the start
>   or stop actions are used.  I'm just bringing it up in case this will
>   cause anyone problems--in which case shout now before it's changed!